# Finding the correct intersection point for a right-hand bend

Tags: java, math, curve

I am trying to calculate curves (their coordinates), for this I have the start point and the end point. I need the center so that I can draw the curve in the right direction. Now the question is, how do I get the correct center?

I have the intersection points of the two circles, and one of these intersection points would be the correct center. But which one is it?

For example, if I have a start point at (50, 50) and an end point at (100, 0), the lower intersection point would be the correct one for a curve to the right.

```
public static Vector2D calculatePoint(Vector2D[] vectors, double alpha, double startingAlpha) {

    if (startingAlpha == 0 && alpha < 180) {
        return getLower(vectors);
    }

    if (startingAlpha == 0 && alpha == 180) {
        return getLeft(vectors);
    }

    if (startingAlpha == 0 && alpha > 180) {
        return getHigher(vectors);
    }

    if (startingAlpha == 90 && alpha < 180) {
        return getHigher(vectors);
    }

    return null;

}
```

The variable `alpha` is the new angle, `startingalpha` is the angle it already has and vectors is the array with the two points.

I have made an example with the `startingAlpha` of 0°.
`Startingalpha` can be between 0° and 360°.

The simple addition of `startingAlpha` and `alpha` would not work either, for example, because in the case of 90° starting and 90° alpha 180° would result and then the left angle would have to be taken. However, since the curve is not 180° but only 90°, **this is wrong.**

Comment: A curve between two points can be almost anything.  Assuming that you want the starting and ending of the curve to be perpendicular, you can easily calculate the two center points, as you have done.  Using your example of 50,50 and 100,0, assuming drawing coordinates, one curve starts at 0 degrees and curves to 90 degrees while the other starts at 90 degrees and curves to 0 degrees, with 0 degrees as north and clockwise positive degrees.  I made so many assumptions in this comment, as you haven't defined your coordinate system in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use trigonometric calculations to find the center of the circle that forms the curve.

```
public static Vector2D calculatePoint(Vector2D[] vectors, double alpha, double startingAlpha) {
    // Calculate the angle between the two vectors
    double angle = Math.abs(alpha - startingAlpha);

    // Calculate the direction of the curve (right or left)
    int direction = (startingAlpha + angle <= 360) ? 1 : -1;

    // Calculate the center of the curve using trigonometry
    double centerX = vectors[0].getX() + direction * vectors[0].distanceTo(vectors[1]) / Math.tan(Math.toRadians(angle / 2));
    double centerY = vectors[0].getY() - direction * vectors[0].distanceTo(vectors[1]) / Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle / 2));

    return new Vector2D(centerX, centerY);
}
```